# How to update android studio IDE manually

Tags: android, android-studio

The issue am having is I have a beta version of android and would like to update it manually to the latest version without loosing my settings and the SDK am already using. I have checked threads and don't seem to find the answer. Most recommmend automatically which can't work for me since my version is too far behind (0.8) from the latest. Am new to this so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Install the latest version, and choose use existing settings when you run it for the first time.

Comment: just using your current version of android Studio to export your current settings and keep it safe in any place and when you install your latest version of android studio just it will automatically get your SDK address and then when it will ask for new settings and Old settings just give the address.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @AVINASHRANJAN I used your solution and it worked like a charm. It automatically detected the SDK. However a follow up issue am having is now it states that gradle is not configured whenever I try to run projects. Any help with that?